# OpenLayer setTileLoadFunction gives Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: openlayers

If I load the same source without the setTileLoadFunction it works fine, but if I load the same tile thru the function below as described in the documentation (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html) I get this error:

```
blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''
```

The function I use to load tiles thru:

```
source.setTileLoadFunction(function(tile, src) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.addEventListener('loadend', function (evt) {
        const data = this.response;
        if (data !== undefined) {
          tile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        } else {
          tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
        }
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
        tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
      });
      xhr.open('GET', src);
      xhr.send();
    });
```

I tried to add this before xhr.send():

```
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

And I have tried "crossOrigin: 'anonymous'" on the source but still the same error..

If the tiles could be loaded thru the "normal way" with just the url in the source, then why is it blocking the same request with XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: To use with XHR or fetch the server (not the client request) must be configured to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests  That is not required with a simple image src but you will get tainted canvas see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#security_and_tainted_canvases

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought this was the way OpenLayers fetched the images "under the hood" and that I just missed  to add something. Then I have to re-think the solution a bit